# Does Frege solve the issue of "re-export qualified" of Haskell?

Tags: haskell, frege

The issue in Haskell:

> ```
> module Foo.A where
>
> foo = 42
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> module Foo.B where
>
> foo = 12
> ```
>
> and you want to write a super module
>
> ```
> module Foo (
>       module Foo.A
>     , module Foo.B
>     ) where
>
> import Foo.A
> import Foo.B
> ```
>
> which re-exports those modules, you would get a name clash.

Note, there can be **plenty of the functions like `foo`** in each module (foo1, foo2, etc) and I want to use them from both modules. There can also be `data`s with the same member names in each module, after all. So hiding isn't a solution. 
I do **not** consider Lens for resolving it.

Now, does Frege solve the problem of "re-export qualified" of Haskell? It seems it does if I remember correctly, but I can't find the evidence now, can anyone elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it doesn't. In Frege, a module can re-export items only (i.e. functions, types, type classes), but not modules.

This means that, if you have some `foo`s down in the module hierarchy you are importing, you still need to hide all but at most one.

What you can do in Frege is:

```
import mod.A(foo fooA)
import mod.B(foo fooB)
```

which effectively renames `A.foo` to `fooA` and `B.foo` to `fooB` in the importing module. This works also on re-exports. For example, in `frege.Prelude` we have

```
import Prelude.PreludeBase public(!= /=)
```

This will cause anyone who imports `frege.Prelude` to have the operator `/=` available. But this is only an alias for the `!=` operator of `Ord`

As one can imagine, we need to have both `!=` and `/=` in order to avoid complaints form the Java or Haskell camps, respectively.